# Get jquery plugin instance in a different js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pikaday

I am using the plugin PikaDay:

https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

On my page, this plugin is being applied to one of my form elements as follows:

```
$('#datepicker').pikaday(config);
```

For one reason or another, I do not have the ability to edit the JS file that this code is being executed from. I can however, add my own new JS files.

I would like to access the pikaday instance created in the original JS file, in my new JS file?

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: it should already be there if its loaded.

Comment: Huh? How do I reference it?

Comment: like any other jquery code. `$`, `jQuery`, `window.$`, `window.jQuery`...

Comment: I'm curious.  Why you're not using `datepicker` from Bootstrap?

Comment: @DanielA.White I need to access the pikaday isntance itself, not the instance of the field its affect.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique where does OP mention they have bootstrap? You wouldn't include Bootstrap just for a datepicker.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod you'll have to look at its api...

Comment: @ADyson can you read my comment again?  It's curiosity, not a suggestion.  Further, you can customize your bootstrap assets for using only datepicker and not the whole set.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique it reads like a suggestion. Why comment if you're suggesting the OP maybe ought to use it? There are hundreds of datepickers out there, why mention the bootstrap one specifically, if you're just curious?

Comment: @ADyson let's stop the conversation because it's pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. If you read the full documentation. They have mentioned it.

Something like this.

```
 var picker = new Pikaday({ field: $('#datepicker')[0] });
```

You can refer `picker` now .

Comment: Thanks. I thought this would re-initialize the Pikaday instance... but it doesn't. So this works well.